# Introduce dummy row in a sybase query

Tags: sql, sybase

I need to introduce a dummy row if my query 1 fails to fetch result.

```
select column1,column2,... from <ActualTable> Where condition='abc'... (1)
Union
select "dummy col1","dummy col2"..... from <dummy table> where col1 NOT IN (select column1 from
<ActualTable> where condition = 'abc'..)                               (2)
```

With the above query if query 1 fetches result query 2 wont. If query 1 has no result then i would get a dummy row.

Is there any other way to achieve the same result in Sybase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temp table if the "ActualTable" gives >1 row

```
select column1,column2,... INTO #temp
from <ActualTable>
Where condition='abc'... (1)

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    select "dummy col1","dummy col2"..... INTO #tmp
    from <dummy table>

-- #temp will exist now

INSERT #temp
select column1,column2,...
from <AnotherTable>
Where condition='abc'... (1)

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    INSERT #temp
    select "dummy col1","dummy col2".....
    from <dummy table>

... 
SELECT * FROM #tmp
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies guys.

i have similar set of union queries may be around 12 sets.. Set 1 = 5 Rows always , Set 2 and Set 3 - returns 1 row each...

    select ....
    UNION
    select ....

    select ....
    UNION
    select ....
    ....
    ....


For these kind how can use ROWCOUNT? Is ROWCOUNT always keeps the count of previous query result?

Comment: Thanks, i'm gone'a try this in the stored procedure in sybase

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select top 1 * from
(
select 0,column1,column2,... from <ActualTable> Where condition='abc'... (1)
Union
select 1,"dummy col1","dummy col2"..... from <dummy table> 
order by 1
)
```

If first query is successful, you will get it, if not, then the second will be returned

Comment: Good point, thanks gbn, I thought from the question he was expecting a single row back...